How can someone install Repast and required dependencies into Eclipse from a machine without Internet access?
The Repast website provides guidance on installing Repast directly into Eclipse per https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install. However, the Eclipse Update Manager assumes that the user has Internet access to reach three URLs from which to download Groovy Eclipse, Xpand SDK 2.2, and Repast. I am working on a machine without Internet access, and this means that I cannot reach the three URLs shown (https://groovy.jfrog.io/ui/native/plugins-release/e4.31/, https://web.cels.anl.gov/projects/Repast/xpand-mirror/, and https://web.cels.anl.gov/projects/Repast/update_site/). I would like to figure out how to install Repast into an installation of Eclipse IDE that I already have on the machine.
I tried reaching the URLs from within the Eclipse Update Manager, but of course they are inaccessible without Internet access. A quick Google search suggested some way to archive the installation sites' contents for placement locally on the machine (from which I would then reference in Eclipse Update Manager) - however, the latter two URLs show a "403 Forbidden" error when I try to reach them in my browser for download, and I am not sure what I would need to try to archive from the first URL (which is reachable from within my browser). So, guidance for installing plugins without Internet access, like at Install the Eclipse CVS plugin without Internet access, is not helpful without more information. I would appreciate any guidance about (1) how to archive / localize these sites for access to install dependencies through Eclipse Update Manager, and (2) how to access the second and third sites shown for archiving / localization once I know how to archive / localize.

Are you able to use any of the current Repast installers?  These installers contain Eclipse, the Repast development libraries, and a JRE.  Alternatively, if you would like to use your own Eclipse instance and install the Repast update site, you can do this on a machine that does have internet access, and then just copy over the entire /eclipse folder to the offline machine.  The Repast libraries and all dependencies should be installed in the /eclipse/plugins folder.

Copy over the entire /eclipse folder, as @EricTatara says, won't work. But you can use this copy to install from via File > Import...: Install >From Existing Installation.

@howlger, would you please clarify the best way to make the copy that I can then import as you have suggested? E.g., should I use File > Export ...: Install >Installed Software Items to File here to export? If so, should I just select to export the Repast Simphony software item, or also things like Groovy Compiler, or maybe just export everything shown in the list of software items that I can export?

Copy the Eclipse IDE installation with all plugins you like to install to e.g. an USB stick and then you can use it as source in File > Import...: Install >From Existing Installation. When you want to transfer platform dependent plugins, both have to be for the same platform (operating system). If you used the Eclipse installer, copy the ~/.p2/pool directory instead.
